# When to use forEach vs map when I am just iterating over something?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I know that map returns a new array, and that forEach does not return anything (the docs say it returns `undefined`).

For example, if I had some code like this:

```
let test;

values.forEach((value, idx) => {
  if (someNumber >= value) {
    test = value;
  }
});
```

Here I am just checking if `someNumber` is greater than some value, and if it is then set `test = value`.  Is there another array method I should use here?

Or is it fine to use `.forEach`

Comment: `var test = values.find(v => v <= someNumber)` can be a way.

Comment: @Redu—that returns the first value to meet the condition, whereas the OP's code returns the last.

Comment: @RobG You might consider to drop that comment to the `Array.some()` involving answers down too... By the way the OP's code implies that requirement in the worst possible way if it even does.

Comment: Use the one that will best do the job. For example, I would use `map` for converting one array into another array of same length, `filter` for filtering an array, `reduce` for reducing an array into one value, etc. As others have pointed out, `some` seems to do the best job in your example. If you're fine with `forEach` go for it, but you might be doing extra work.

Comment: sorry it was not clear.  basically if the number is great than or equal to the value from the array at whatever index, stop, and set `test` equal to that value .

Comment: @user1354934 And this is exactly what my answer provides (:

Comment: @Redu—if the OP compares results from their current code to your "answer", they might wonder why there are differences. I'm just pointing that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example doesn't make sense because it finds the *last* `value` that is less than or equal to `someNumber`, repeatedly assigning to the `test` variable if more than one is found. Thus, your code is not truly expressing your intent well since other developers can be confused about what you're trying to achieve. In fact, other answers here have had differing opinions on your goal due to this ambiguity. You even said:

> if the number is great than or equal to the value from the array at whatever index, stop, and set test equal to that value

But your code doesn't stop at the first value! It keeps going through the entire array and the result in `test` will be the *last* value, not the *first* one.

In general, making your loop refer to outside variables is not the best way to express your intent. It makes it harder for the reader to understand what you're doing. It's better if the function you use returns a value so that it's clear the variable is being assigned.

Here's a guide for you:

**[forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)**

Use this when you want to iterate over all the values in order to do something with each of them. Don't use this if you are creating a new output value--but do  use it if you need to modify existing items or run a method on each one, where the `forEach` has no logical output value. [array.forEach at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) says:

> There is no way to stop or break a forEach() loop other than by throwing an exception. If you need such behavior, the forEach() method is the wrong tool, use a plain loop instead. If you are testing the array elements for a predicate and need a Boolean return value, you can use every() or some() instead. If available, the new methods find() or findIndex() can be used for early termination upon true predicates as well.

**[find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)**

Use this when you want to find the first instance of something, and stop. What you *said* makes it sound like you want this:

```
let testResult = values.find(value => value <= someNumber);
```

This is far superior to setting the `test` value from inside the lambda or a loop. I also think that reversing the inequality and the variables is better because of the way we tend to think about lambdas.

**[some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)**

These only give you a Boolean as a result, so you have to misuse them slightly to get an output value. It will traverse the array until the condition is true or the traversal is complete, but you have to do something a bit hacky to get any array value out. Instead, use `find` as above, which is intended to output the found value instead of simply a true/false whether the condition is met by any element in the array.

**[every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)**

This is similar to `some` in that it returns a `Boolean`, but is what you would expect, it is only true if all the items in the array meet the condition. It will traverse the array until the condition is false or the traversal is complete. Again, don't misuse it by throwing away the Boolean result and setting a variable to a value. If you want to do something to every item in an array and return a single value, at that point you would want to use `reduce`. Also, notice that `!arr.every(lambdacondition)` is the same as `arr.some(!lambdacondition)`.

**[reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)**

The way your code is actually written—finding the last value that matches the condition—naturally lends itself to `reduce`:

```
let testResult = values.reduce(
   (recent, value) => {
      if (value <= someNumber) {
         recent = value;
      }
      return recent;
   },
   undefined
);
```

This does the same job of finding the last value as your example code does.

**[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)**

`map` is for when you want to transform each element of an array into a new array of the same length. If you have any experience with C# it is much like the Linq-to-objects `.Select` method. For example:

```
let inputs = [ 1, 2, 3, 4];
let doubleInputs = inputs.map(value => value * 2);
// result: [ 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

**New requirements**

Given your new description of finding the adjacent values in a sorted array between which some value can be found, consider this code:

```
let sortedBoundaries = [ 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 ];
let inputValue = 37;
let interval = sortedBoundaries
   .map((value, index) => ({ prev: value, next: sortedBoundaries[index + 1] }))
   .find(pair => pair.prev < inputValue && inputValue <= pair.next);
// result: { prev: 20, next: 30 }
```

You can improve this to work on the ends so that a number > 50 or <= 10 will be found as well (for example, `{ prev: undefined, next: 10 }`).

**Final notes**

By using this coding style of returning a value instead of modifying an outside variable, you not only communicate your intent better to other developers, you then get the chance to use `const` instead of `let` if the variable will not be reassigned afterward.

I encourage you to browse the documentation of the various `Array` prototype functions at MDN—doing this will help you sort them out. Note that each method I listed is a link to the MDN documentation.

Comment: if I use find though, here's the issue:  if I have a array like: `[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]` and I do find where less than or equal to 35, it will return 10.  I am trying to get 30 :(

Comment: This is completely new information. You need to do a seriously better job specifying your requirements. Is your array sorted and guaranteed to be sorted? You can use the `reduce` method to get the right value if the array is sorted, but if not, no one has even come close to giving you the right answer (due to not giving us the right question). Please answer about sorting and I will try to respond soonish—though away from a computer for a while now.

Comment: sorry ErikE.  I will work on asking better questions.  No worries if you can't reply soonish I think I need to review my arrays first.  I have a sorted array and I am learning about ranges so I was just trying to find given a number, which two numbers is it between.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use `Array#some`, instead of `Array#forEach`.

`Array#forEach` **keeps** iterating the array even if given condition was fulfilled.

`Array#some` **stops** iteration when given condition was fulfilled.

One of the advantages would be connected with performance, another - depends on your purposes - `Array#forEach` keeps overwriting the result with every passed condition, `Array#some` assigns the first found value and stops the iteration.

```js
let test,
    values = [4,5,6,7],
    someNumber = 5;

values.some((value, idx) => {
  if (someNumber >= value) {
    test = value;
    return test;
  }
});

console.log(test);
```

Comment: *some* only returns a boolean, whereas the OP's code returns the last value that satisfied the condition.

Comment: @RobG I have no idea from where did you get such conclusion. Yes, it does return a `boolean` but depends on it's value `(true/false)` it returns a specified element from the array. And about the OPs code, yes **his code does return the last one**, but what's the point then if OP actually needs to find if **even** one of the elements fulfills the condition? Anyways - OP didn't specify if he wants the first one or the last one. **Edit**: Now he did.

Comment: @Kinduser He DID specify he wants the last value because that's what his example code does.

Comment: @ErikE Read the comments. *"if the number is great than or equal to the value from the array at whatever index, stop, and set test equal to that value"*

Comment: @ErikE I'm going to sleep soon but I will wait here for your feedback. What's wrong with my solution then and what's your proposal?

Comment: @ErikE It's all good mate, I didn't even think about it this way.

Comment: if I put a console.lot outsdie of the `if` to log the index, it will still log the index til the end of array.  however it only logs the index after the if was satisfied.  is that how its supposed to work?

Comment: @Kinduser I have posted an answer, my comments on `some` should make clear what my objection to your answer is.

Comment: "*I have no idea from where did you get such conclusion*". It comes from what the code does. The value returned by the function is coerced to boolean, so if it's 0 (which might be the only number greater than (*someNumber*), it will be coerced to false and the function keeps running. It will set *test* to the correct value though.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use the [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method.

```
let test;
const someNumber = 10;

[1, 5, 10, 15].some(function (value) {
  if (value > someNumber) {
    return test = value
  } 
})
```

One advantage to the `.some()` method over your original solution is optimization, as it will `return` once the condition has been met.

Comment: The value returned by the callback is coerced to a boolean, so this won't actually return the value and may return strange results (e.g. if test is say -1 and value is 0, which will be coerced to false). See [*ECMA-262:Array.prototype.some*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.some).

Comment: That is correct, but we're not interested in what the callback returns. We only need to assign `test` to the `value`.

Answer (score 0):

How about Object?
you can search with for-of